# How can I get the file after Service Hook (Code pushed) event?

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a Service Hook triggering on *Code pushed*. I get the event working, but I can't figure out how to get the reference to the files that was pushed.

When using GitHub hooks I get a reference to each commited/pushed file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the changed files through REST API programming after receiving the service hook notification.

[With changed items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#with-changed-items)